# Tailwind HeadlessUI toggle switch with label in between

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css, headless-ui

Based on the toggle switch in the headlessui, I have like to place a text in between the switch.  I came out with something like below but the text simply follow the inner rounded button.  Is there a way that I can place the text(enable/disable) on the left or right hand side of the inner button?

https://headlessui.dev/react/switch

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { Switch } from '@headlessui/react'

const App = () => {
  const [enabled, setEnabled] = useState(false)

  return (
    <Switch.Group>
      <div className='flex items-center'>
        <Switch
          checked={enabled}
          onChange={setEnabled}
          className={`${
            enabled ? 'bg-blue-600' : 'bg-gray-200'
          } relative inline-flex items-center h-12 rounded-full w-48 transition-colors focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-offset-2 focus:ring-indigo-500`}
        >
          <span
            className={`${
              enabled ? 'translate-x-32' : 'translate-x-1'
            } inline-block w-12 h-11 transform bg-white rounded-full transition-transform`}
          >
            {enabled ? 'Enable' : 'Disable'}
          </span>
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </Switch.Group>
  )
}

export default App
```

Answer (score 0):

You could give the `span` `absolute` class then replace `translate-x-32` with `left-0` and `translate-x-1` with `right-0`

then add another `span` for the text and then add `flex justify-center items-center` to the `Switch` to justify the text in the center look here

Comment: it helps.  Do you know how I can put the text 'enable' 'disable' right in the center of this whole switching button?  Now the text just follows the inner circular button

Comment: @DarylWong You need to add another `span` for the text and then add `flex justify-center items-center`  to the `Switch` to justify the text in the center look [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/tailwind-css-and-react-forked-6d4bdk?file=/src/App.js) ,I will update my answer.